# warning: else without rescue is useless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, warnings, switch-statement

This code block here throws a warning message in Rails console -- warning: else without rescue is useless

```
  def handle_exceptions(e)
    case e
    when ActionController::UnknownAction, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActionController::RoutingError
      not_found  
    else
      internal_error(e)
    end
  end
```

Any clue why?

Comment: I've tried in my rails 3.1.3 console using ruby 1.9.3p0 and seems to be working "fine". I mean no warning... What ruby and rails are you using?

Comment: I tried it in rails 3.1.0 console with ruby 1.9.2p290. I do not get the warning. But I get NoMethodError: undefined method `internal_error' for main:Object. If i make this method I get no errors

Comment: What version of rails. I think this is a problem with rails, not ruby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think that this error is not from the source code you posted but from where it is called.

i can prove it with this implementation, which also uses 1.9.2-p290:

```
module ActionController
  class UnknownAction; end
  class RoutingError; end
end

module ActiveRecord
  class RecordNotFound; end
end

class Test

  def test_exception
    raise "error"
  rescue
    handle_exceptions($!)
  end

  def test_failing
    else puts "invalid"
    end
  end

  def not_found
    puts "not found"
  end

  def internal_error(e)
    puts e
  end

  def handle_exceptions(e)
    case e
    when ActionController::UnknownAction, ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActionController::RoutingError
      not_found
    else
      internal_error(e)
    end
  end
end

Test.new.test_exception
Test.new.test_failing
```